# Excel macro: How to extract data from other Excel file

Tags: vba, excel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [excel macro: browse excel file and use its worksheet data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12380901/excel-macro-browse-excel-file-and-use-its-worksheet-data)

In brief, I want to write a script can do this.
In the current excel file, there is a macro button. The user can click the button to browse files (another Excel). In that browsed Excel, several worksheets will be load to current Excel workbook and the data will be used.
I write like this

```
Sub Button1_Click()     ' choose LOAD path

    objFile = Application.GetOpenFilename(fileFilter:="All Files (* . *) , * . * ")   ' browse function

    ...    ' following

    Call main_function
End Sub
```

I write the browse function already. but how to write the following part? eg. the certain worksheet's data in objFile will be used in main_function.

Answer (score 2):

While what you want isn't really clear (I'm not confident I understand your question's intent) I will have a crack at this.

Assuming you have the name of the file you'd like to open in objFile, you can go about extracting data from that spreadsheet like this - I just open the selected workbook, then write the name of all of the sheets in it to Column A in whichever sheet was open before the button was pressed.

Opening a new workbook causes it to be brought to the foreground - so if I didn't grab the active sheet before opening a new book, then set it after opening the new one, you'd end up overwriting data in the workbook you just opened.

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    ' choose LOAD path
    objFile = Application.GetOpenFilename(fileFilter:="All Files (* . *) , * . * ")   ' browse function

    Set curSheet = ActiveSheet
    Set mWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(objFile)
    curSheet.Activate

    Call someFunction(curSheet, mWorkbook)
End Sub


Sub someFunction(targetSheet, srcWorkbook)
    numSheets = srcWorkbook.Sheets.Count
    For i = 1 To numSheets
        targetSheet.Cells(i, 1) = srcWorkbook.Sheets(i).Name
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: thx!~ i tried another method instead. copy the entire worksheets to current workbook. but the disadvantage is after use, the user need to click "delete" to delete those copied worksheets. actually, what I want is just read the data, not copy and paste. It means import & use other workbook's data without trace. Im not sure whether can do this.

Comment: Pleasure. Can you elaborate on what it is you want to do? You can use mWorkbook from any function you pass it to. With that variable, you can read any data in the excel file. You don't need to copy the data from one place to another, unless you actually want it in the other place. So, as I say - if you can further elaborate on your intentions, I'll be in a position to provide you a better answer.